# How do I reduce the quota I use to query viewCount on all videos of a channel?

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Let me first describe why I need this:

Everytime I find a new channel I want to watch some of the most popular videos to get an idea of it. Looking for the most popular video is not always very helpful, because it might be very old or just one viral video. So I want to find the most popular video recently uploaded. The idea is to calculate a score per video: score = views / hoursSinceUpload

So first question is if there already exists something like this, I didn't find anything.

So I coded it myself and its working pretty well, but checking one channel uses a lot of my quota. It comes down to getting the viewCount for every video of a channel which has to be done by one request for every video.

Is there a way to get multiple viewCounts with one request?

Obviously there is a reason that the free limit is 10.000 per day, but still...

Also, since the point is to get the most popular video in recent times and don't need all the videos and could reduce the requests this way, but I still want to know if I'm overlooking something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce quite significantly the number of API calls to the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint by making use of the following feature of its `id` request parameter (the emphasis below is mine):

> [**`id`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) (string)
>
> The `id` parameter specifies a *comma-separated list of the YouTube video ID(s)* for the resource(s) that are being retrieved. In a video resource, the `id` property specifies the video's ID.

Although not documented explicitly, the comma-separated list of IDs can have at most 50 items.

As a consequence, for a set of `N` video IDs, instead of having to call `Videos.list` `N` times, you can reduce the number of calls to `floor(N / 50) + (N % 50 ? 1 : 0)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for, helps a lot :)